# Can you create Program Files x86 by yourself?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-folders

I attached a second SSD and was wondering if creating a Program File (x86) folder “by hand” or manually and following the exact formatting the same as it being created by a program automatically.

I know there are differences that the x86 folder has and I am curious as to if it will operate and have the same properties if I were to create it manually as oppose to it being generated automatically.

Using windows 10 home.

Answer (score 0):

Windows only needs one Program Files and Program Files (x86). Even if you have two disks (I do on one machine) there is still just one PF and one PF (x86). No need for more. Let Windows create these and I recommend you not do it yourself

Comment: So if I for example want to install steam on the secondary non windows (C:) drive. Would I just change the installation path to D:\? This program normally requires a program files folder, cannot just be in the drive without a program files folder?

Assuming the second drive is D:

Comment: You could do that. Best practice is to keep programs on the Windows Drive (the one with Program Files). Data including Program Data can be located on the non-Windows drive. Just programs does not use that much data (about 10 GB on my quite full machine)

Answer (score 0):

Windows *requires* that these folders match the known installation locations, as shown in the [environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594066/how-to-get-program-files-x86-env-variable). For example, for the'x86 location, enter the following in CMD:

```
echo %programfiles(x86)%
```

You can *change* the location for system folders, but might get odd results if the `Windows`, `User`, `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)` and `ProgramData` folders are not on the same partition. Use Nirsoft's [Special Folders View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html) to view them and the associated environment variables. Use [Windows Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/moving-your-personal-data-folders-in-windows-vista-the-easy-way/) to change the folder locations; since Music, Pictures and Videos may be the largest folders, they're prime candidates to move to a larger drive.

Remember, [Location, Location, Location](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/06/28/magazine/28FOB-onlanguage-t.html).

Comment: So if I for example want to install steam on the secondary non windows (C:) drive. Would I just change the installation path to D:\? This program normally requires a program files folder, cannot just be in the drive without a program files folder?

Assuming the second drive is D:

Comment: @Luke - You can install Steam and any game on Steam to any directory you want. Steam will create the folder with the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

> Can you create Program Files x86 by yourself?

First thing you should know about the x86 version of the Program Files folder.

This folder only exists on 64-bit installations of Windows. Given that it is possible to install a 32-bit version of Windows, if you do so, no Program Files X86 will exists, and the Program Files folder will automatically be the one where X86 programs are installed, since no X64 programs can run on the system.

When using a 64-bit version of Windows, Windows installers will automatically install programs to the Program Files or Program Files x86 folder depending on if its the x86 or x64 version of that program. Windows will create that folder at the location where it expects it to be during install.

If you create this folder somewhere on your disk, windows will not know about it and thus won't start using it. Creating it yourself has no value at all.

The Program Files folders are special though. Inside the program files folder, there are the Common Files folder. Windows will install libraries here that other programs depends upon, and if these don't exist with the correct content inside, various parts of windows will break and some programs won't start anymore. In addition, the Program Files folders have special rights attached to them. By default TRUSTED INSTALLER is owner of these files, allowing most installers to install programs without requiring administrative rights. (sadly, most installers need to modify more than just placing files in the Program Files folder though, and as such still require administrative elevation)

The location of the Program Files folders are defined at various locations, such as many places in the registry and the environmental variables.

It is possible to alter these if you want to move the Program Files folder, but if not done succesfully, it will break things (I speak from experience).

Now, I assume your objective here is to create a new location for programs to be installed to while maintaining the original Program Files folders, and you wonder if this can be done?

Yes. You can do this. You can create a new folder and name it anything you want even, and place that folder anywhere you want. You have to keep in mind though, that by default an installation will be installed to the Program Files folder, so you have to choose a custom/manual installation, and change the target location of where the program is installed to your new folder for every single installation.

Lastly, it is possible to move the entire Program Files folders to a different drive entirely, but it requires a lot of knowledge of the system and how to do things. I would recommend against this unless you have a fair bit of knowledge and don't mind reinstalling windows in case things break beyond repair.

The steps would be to boot into Windows Setup, then hit Shift-F10 to enter command prompt (you need to be outside of Windows in order to avoid file locks of open programs and services)

Now, you move the folders to its new location, and replace them with junctions (`mklink /j "C:\Program Files" d:\new_location\Programs` for example)

There still will be a C:\Program Files, but it just links to the new location.

EDIT:
In the comments on the other answers, you ask if you can install steam anywhere. Yes you can. In addition, inside steam, you can also specify that games themselves are installed elsewhere. You do not have to reinstall steam. You can just change where games are installed and relocate them from within steam, which is most likely going to be your preferred solution.

To manage this, Right-click the steam icon in your system tray, and go to settings. Go to Downloads, and at the top right, select <kbd>Steam library folders</kbd>. You can add a folder there. Do note, the folder has to be on a different drive, else Steam will not allow you to select the new folder.

Comment: Would a solution to making Windows create the Program Files and Program Files x86 folders that would work like the ones on the C: drive be to simply change the drive letter during installation if the specific program allows it and have it create those folders?

Comment: During installation, you can install anywhere, it does not have to be called Program Files even. So you can say browse, and change to D:\MyStuff\Program if you wanted

Comment: Will there not be an issue since Program Files and Program Files (x86) have special properties and will there be no issue if I name the folder something random and install programs to them? Also if I name the folders in the secondary drive Program Files and Program Files (x86) will there be no conflict or collisions, Will the properties carry over that the C: drive folders have like the specific 32 bit Program Files x86 properties?

Comment: There will not be any conflict. Properties are not carried over, and that is not a requirement either. The only thing you need is that you have permission to write there. The Program Files folder is a restricted but special folder, any other location especially on another drive is almost always completely free of rights and can be written to without requiring administrative rights. You can mix x64 and x86 apps in the same folder if you want.

Comment: So naming folders in a secondary ssd will not cause conflict of names the same as Program Files and Program Files (x86)? It would also not make a difference if they are called that on a secondary drive as they are C: drive special?

Comment: Yes. All of that is true.